# Jquery Delay slideDown using time();

Tags: jquery, delay, slidedown

Sorry I could not find this.

```
$('div#loader').slideDown("fast").delay(1.5);
```

Does not word as expected, I want it to `slideDown`, then stay in that mode for 1.5 seconds and then the load function which happens very fast and then it slides up using fast. I thought `delay();` was the correct approach.

Full function for those who wish to see:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function last_msg_funtion() {
        var ID = $(".pic_box:last").attr("id");
        $('div#loader').slideDown("fast").delay(1.5);
        $.post("/?action=get&id=" + ID,
        function (data) {
            if (data!="") {
                $(".pic_box:last").after(data);
            }
            $('div#loader').slideUp("fast");
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `wait` helper function and run your code after waiting for 1.5 secs:

```
$.wait = function(time) {
  return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, time);
  });
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    function last_msg_funtion() {
        var ID = $(".pic_box:last").attr("id");
        $('div#loader').slideDown("fast");
        $.wait(1500).then(function() {
            $.post("/?action=get&id=" + ID, function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    $(".pic_box:last").after(data);
                }
                $('div#loader').slideUp("fast");
            });
        });
    };
});
```

The `wait` function makes your code reads better IMO

Comment: No I want the slider loader to come into view for 1.5 seconds then disappear then my post command executed. We cannot do the other way (thanks for posting) sheer traffic and the UI/UX - dont want to make it laggy.

Answer (score 2):

Delay only delays functions that come after it in the chian, so it is delaying nothing there. You are better off using `setTimeout` here IMO

```
$('div#loader').slideDown("fast", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    $.post("/?action=get&id=" + ID,
    function (data) {
        if (data!="") {
            $(".pic_box:last").after(data);
        }
        $('div#loader').slideUp("fast");
    });
}, 1500);
});
```

Here is the delay code if you are interested,

```
// Based off of the plugin by Clint Helfers, with permission.
// http://blindsignals.com/index.php/2009/07/jquery-delay/
delay: function( time, type ) {
    time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[ time ] || time : time;
    type = type || "fx";

    return this.queue( type, function( next, hooks ) {
        var timeout = setTimeout( next, time );
        hooks.stop = function() {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        };
    });
},
```

You can see how it only takes whatever is next in the function chain and delays that.

Comment: But this function shows the loading icon even though the post has loaded the data. I want to delay the post function due to server load. So I use the load icon first, delay and the continue through the JavaScript.

Comment: It's better to set timeout in `slideDown` callback. so we don't need to change timeout delay even if sliding speed is changed.